# Why is my reasoning to derive the bistatic radar equation wrong?

Tags: doppler-effect, radar

The ideal effective antenna aperture is calculated from $A_{eff}=G\lambda^2/4\pi$, G being the antenna gain.

Why is it that in a bistatic radar setup with a transmitter and receiver fixed on the Earth and a moving aircraft, the bistatic radar equation only contains the transmitter wavelength, and nowhere the two Doppler-shifted ones?

If I wanted to determine the received power, I would consider the transmitter's wavelength $\lambda_0$ to calculate its $A_{eff, 0}$, the Doppler-shifted wavelength $\lambda_1$ on the reflecting aircraft as an intermediate receiver and transmitter antenna to calculate its $A_{eff, 1}$, and finally the Doppler-shifted wavelength $\lambda_2$ at the receiver antenna on the ground to calculate its $A_{eff,2}$.

What is wrong with this reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is logically right even for monostatic radar when detecting a moving target. As for your question, you need to note that the radar equation is merely used to calculate the *power* received from the target to the receiver antenna, in order to calculate the maximum detection range of the radar given its minimum acceptable SNR: (The $A_{eff}$ formula is incorporated in this equation)
$$P_r = {{P_t G_t G_r \sigma \lambda^2}\over{{(4\pi)}^3 R_t^2R_r^2}}$$

you can see that power drops with $1/R^4$ and signals at the receiver are usually exceedingly attenuated.

Now the doppler frequency of the reflected signal is:
$$f_D \approx \frac{2V}{c}f_0\rightarrow \lambda'=\frac{c}{f_0+f_D}\approx \lambda_0(1-\frac{2V}{c})$$
The maximum possible speed that you can think of when designing a radar is much lower than 20 Mach (around 7 km/s) even for ballistic missile detection. A speed of 15 km/s gives $\dfrac{2V}{c}=10^{-4}$

Thus, insterting this modified $\lambda$ in the radar equation doesn't affect *anything at all* and is always neglected compared to other losses and sources of noise in the SNR equation.